# Thirdweb/Foundry compilation failed: ChildProcess

Tags: compiler-errors, blockchain, solidity, forge, thirdweb

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9ZM6.png)

Currently trying to deploy a smart contract however im getting this error message every time

i've tried to use the command it gives me: 'forge build --extra-output metadata;' and when i do, i'm prompted with: Error: ’build’ is not a Forge command.

Cant seem to find any information on the issue either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update foundry with `foudryup` and it will work, if not add `evm_version` paris in foundry config.